# How to pause a movie at a given time ?IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, video, nstimer, movie

I wanna pause a movie at a given time,and then an action to continue for many times.
i have try NSTimer like this:

```
#define Timer 0.05
#define Accuracy 0.025

pauseTimeArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.00],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.00],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:15.00] , nil];


    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(timeAction) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void)timeAction{

if (_moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying) {

    NSNumber * positionNum = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:_moviePlayer.currentPlaybackTime];

    float positionFloat = [positionNum floatValue];

    for (NSNumber * pauseNum in _pauseTimeArray) {

        float pauseFloat = [pauseNum floatValue];

        float differentFloat = fabsf(pauseFloat - positionFloat);

        if (differentFloat < Accuracy) {
            [_moviePlayer pause];
        }
    }
}
```

}

And when i paused and play again , it occasionally paused. and the differentFloat < Accuracy.

could someone give another idear without NStimer,or something else.Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is good but it needs some improvements to work correctly.
Instead of checking `positionFloat` in range of `pauseFloat` +/-`Accuracy` keep your last pause time, as checkpoint. Then if `positionFloat` is greater than this checkpoint - pause movie and set next checkpoint.

```
pauseTimeArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.00],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.00],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:15.00] , nil];
uint currentCheckpoint = 0;

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(timeAction) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void)timeAction{

if (_moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying) {

    NSNumber * positionNum = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:_moviePlayer.currentPlaybackTime];

    float positionFloat = [positionNum floatValue];

        float pauseFloat = [[pauseTimeArray objectAtIndex: currentCheckpoint] floatValue];

        if (positionFloat > pauseFloat) {
            [_moviePlayer pause];
            currentCheckpoint++;
        }
    }
}
```

And of course, check if currentCheckpoint is inside your pauseTimeArray bounds.